# Why does my docker image keep crashing when I try and build it due to a syntax error that is not making sense?

Tags: docker, syntax

I am trying to build a mysql container using a docker file and an SQL file to create the tables but I keep getting this error in my terminal:`> [3/3] RUN /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql: #7 0.686 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token``('
'7 0.686 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql: line 1: ``CREATE TABLE "articulos" (`

where it says I have a "`" in from of CREATE and I don't why that's showing up.

here is my docker file

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE books

COPY  ./sqlscript /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql
```

and this is my SQL file

```
CREATE TABLE "articulos" (
"id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
"titulo" text,
"contenido" text,
"fechacreacion" date DEFAULT NULL,
"categoria" text,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You try to "execute" an SQL script. This cannot work. What you probably meant is something like `RUN mysql < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql`. This, however, will not work since mysql is not started at container build time. --- As an aside: the documentation of the [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) states that `.sql`-scripts located in `/docker-netrypoint-initdb.d` are executed on database startup. So the sql-file would actually executed twice, resulting in an error the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be facing two problems:

1. Docker is trying to run your `.sql` file as if it was a `bash` script
2. And anyway, your MySQL server might not be running when building

Try removing your last Dockerfile line (`RUN /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/books.sql` ).

It might work like you want it to since I presume that `.sql` files placed in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory are executed on startup.

Comment: "*It might work like you want it to since I presume...*" - No need to presume. The [msql dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) states that it does =)

Answer (score 1):

The `RUN` keyword is to execute a command. The SQL schema file isn't an executable. If you look at the documentation for the MySQL container, it should automatically load all schema files located in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` when it first starts. So you really just need the following:

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE books
COPY  ./books.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

...and make sure your SQL file is named `books.sql` in the current working directory. (Not sure what `sqlscript` is in your original question).